# How to make the code run faster, possibly replacing the for loops in his code? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance, for-loop

```
import numpy as np

list_shot = list(np.arange(0, 100, 50)) 
list_lens = list(np.arange(10))
list_total = []

for shot in list_shot:
    print("-", shot)
    list_out = []

    for lens in list_lens:
        val = shot * lens
        list_out.append(val)
    print(list_out)

    list_total.append(list_out)
```

Basically, the above code is just a simple representation of this code below that needs to be optimised for it to run faster.

```
CN_list_shot = []
counter = 0

for shot in bec[1:1000:500]: ### reads from time snapshots
    CN_list = []
    for length in length_list: ### all the lenghts for the same snapshot 
        i = neighbor_list("i", shot, {('Ge', 'Ge'): length}, self_interaction= False)
        coord = np.bincount(i)
        CN_list.append(np.sum(coord) / np.count_nonzero(coord))
            
        print("CN_list: ", CN_list) ### value added to the list for the snapshot    
    
    CN_list_shot.append(CN_List) ### the list added for each snapshots
```

Comment: What do you want to replace the for loops with?

Comment: @mkrieger1 That is exactly, I am struggling with. What do you suggest?

Comment: If your code works, but you just want the efficiency improved, then [codereview.se] might be a better fit (assuming you flesh out the details with some sample input and output and a description of the problem)

Comment: The inner for seems like a good candidate for a call to map

Comment: It's already pretty fast. Why do you want to make it faster? Are you running this code on two much larger lists? If so, please include that.

Comment: @jhschwartz Yeah, you can see in the code below the sample one, the number of snapshots can be 10000 and for each of them the lengths can be ```length_list = np.arange(0, 13, 0.01)```. So, it takes ages for it to calculate the desired properties.

Comment: @Saha_1994 the linear algebra methods people are recommending are probably the way to go. But, you might have luck with [numba](https://numba.pydata.org) if for some reason you really want to keep your loops...

Comment: You should count my answer as correct if you like it :)

Comment: OP also posted the same question on a different Stack: [Is there a way to do array broadcasting faster, or without using loops?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8470)

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a simpler way to achieve this using linear algebra methods. When using `numpy` try to avoid transforming a `numpy` array back to a python list. This defeats the purpose.

Essentially, what you are doing here is a simple matrix multiplication. All you have to do is reshape the `numpy` arrays in order to achieve what you want.

```
import numpy as np

list_shot = np.arange(0, 100, 50).reshape((2, 1))
list_lens = np.arange(10).reshape((1, 10))
print(list_shot)
print(list_lens)
print(np.matmul(list_shot, list_lens))
```

Output:

```
[[ 0]
 [50]]
[[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]
[[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0  50 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450]]
```

Comment: The question was unfortunately asked in two separate places at the same time. If you think your code is faster than the others, and can give rough CPU timings, you're welcome to add an answer there too: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8470/5